# What does it mean to "schedule" a coroutine on a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, coroutine

Coming from Python, my understanding of coroutine is that a function can return control back to a main 'event loop', and that event loop is like a task scheduler and whenever a coroutine function does an await, it yields control to the event loop, the event loop will try to run another function in its schedule, until that the awaited function completes, and so on and so forth. At any given time, only one function is running in a single thread. And I understood that as coroutine can achieve concurrency without parallelism (ie, single thread).

Now coming to coroutines in c++, i keep reading out scheduling a coroutine on a threadpool. This confuses me. I thought the whole point of coroutines is so you dont have to us threads? What does it mean to schedule a coroutine on a threadpool? Coroutine A is scheduled on thread 1, and coroutine B is scheduled on thread 2? If so, why not get of coroutines and schedule a regular function on thread 1 and another on thread 2?

Comment: Unlike Python, C++ does not have a built-in event loop. To "schedule" a coroutine to resume on a thread, you have to arrange for it to run on that thread *somehow*. One way is to create a thread and tell the thread "Run this coroutine continuation." Another way is to ask the system threadpool, "Hey, when you get a chance, run this coroutine continuation, please." But you don't have to use a new thread. You could run all continuations on the same thread: When an awaitable becomes ready, it just runs the continuation directly on whatever thread it became ready on.

Comment: think of a coroutine as a function that can return-resume from many points. All the other mechanisms like event loop, task scheduler, threads, threadpool, etc are where you can keep this coroutine for execution.

Comment: @RaymondChen can a coroutine starts on thread A, and resumes on thread B ? What is the 'task scheduler' that makes this cross-thread coroutine start-resume possible ?

Comment: In C++, you the programmer decide how and where coroutines start and resume. The coroutine infrastructure itself has no policy. The programmer provides the policy. You might have a policy that resumes all coroutines on the same thread. You might have a policy that resumes all coroutines on new threads. You might have multiple policies for different kinds of coroutines. It's all up to you. The language give you the flexibility to do it however you like.